# Obtaining Fourier Coefficients without calculating them?

Tags: fourier-series

I have a graph for a function $f(x)$:
[image]

If I have the fourier series representation of the function, is it possible for me to obtain the fourier coefficients without actually having to calculate them? Would I be able to do this using the graph and the representation I have?

$$f(x) = a_0 + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left( a_n\cdot \cos(nx) + b_n \cdot \sin(nx) \right)$$

Even if we can't obtain the exact value of the coefficients I think we have enough to at least determine if any of the coefficients ($a_0, a_n$ or $b_n$) are equal to $0$?

I'm just wondering if this is possible

Comment: You can determine about half of the coefficients just noting that $f$ is an odd function.

Comment: As function is odd, all $a_n$ and $a_0$ will be zero.

Comment: Is that using the idea that since the function is odd, all 'an' are 0 and 'bn' are not 0?

Comment: Oh just saw what @Yalikesifulei wrote after I sent my last comment

Comment: Ok that makes sense, so we used the graph to help determine whether the function was odd or even and that told us the information we wanted to know, right?

Comment: I set up math formatting for you.  In the future, you can find instructions [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: If I recall correctly, the coefficients are themselves sine and cosine functions.

Comment: @RobertTheTutor Kind of, but they are evaluated in $k\pi$, therefore it's just zeros and plus-minus ones. Divided by some power of $k$.